# Trigger Istio to create a new load balancer on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, istio

## **Scenario**

In the midst of updating some resources in AWS, the load balancer that Istio automatically provisioned and tied to the `istio-ingressgateway` Service was deleted. I need a new one before I can update the DNS records, but am not sure how to trigger Istio to create a new one. I'm specifically curious if I can avoid creating one manually and updating the Service in-place. I already tried bouncing the Deployment, which of course didn't change anything about the Service.

## **Question**

Is there a way to cause Istio, deployed in an EKS cluster, to provision a new load balancer in AWS for the `istio-ingressgateway` Service? Only asking after a full read-through of Istio's docs. My hunch is the answer is no, but thought I would ask if someone else has ever managed this before.

Comment: This isn't the responsibility of istio, it's done either by either k8s itself, or by the aws-load-balancer-controller.

Comment: I'm not using the AWS Load Balancer Controller, just using Istio with its Gateway/VirtualService objects. Upon installation, Istio provisions a load balancer and connects it to the default `istio-ingressgateway` Service, dynamically updating that manifest with the load balancer's information. I'm curious if it is possible to cause it to do this again without re-installing.

Comment: Istio does not provision load balancers. That's done by k8s itself when it sees a service with type "LoadBalancer". If you also have aws-load-balancer-controller, this extends the capabilities for load balancer creation on AWS. Re-creation should have happened automatically by k8s, but you can try deleting and recreating the service definition.

Comment: @jordanm has it right here. I was looking at my external-dns and cluster-autoscaler IAM-role-for-Service-Account configurations and assuming Istio followed the same pattern, but it actually has nothing of that sort. Thus, so far as I can tell, you can't trigger Istio to do anything, you have to trigger k8s by re-creating the service. Thanks for the direction @jordanm!